# X509AuthenticationFilter methods return null

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring security to try and authenticate (and eventually authorize) using a client certificate. I already got it to authenticate using httpBasic.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/status", "/configure")
                .access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .denyAll()
            .and().x509()
                .x509AuthenticationFilter(new AuthenticationFilter())
//            .and().httpBasic()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("dashboard.xxxx.yyy.zzz")
            .password("{noop}password").roles("ADMIN");
    }

}
```

I added a custom authentication filter so that I could toss in some logging, and both methods are returning null.

```
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.x509.X509AuthenticationFilter;

public class AuthenticationFilter extends X509AuthenticationFilter {

    private static Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);

    public Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        LOG.info("" + super.getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(request));
        return super.getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(request);
    }

    public Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        LOG.info("" + super.getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(request));
        return super.getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(request);
    }

}
```

Here is my tomcat server.xml connector.

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
        maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
        keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat9/conf/dashboard.p12"
        keystorePass="************" clientAuth="false"
        sslProtocol="TLS" alias="dashboard"
        sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"/>
```

Any ideas what I might be missing, or just doing incorrectly?

I am sending the client certificate via curl using --key and --cert. The --trace - option shows no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Completely unrelated to Spring security.

The solution was to configure the server.xml to ask for the certificate.

```
<SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.2" certificateVerification="required">
```